# Highlight Unicode Characters

Tags: highlight, conceal, unicode

Is it possible to highlight unicode characters?

When I copy/paste a code sample I sometimes run into problems because the website uses `‐`, `‑`, `‒` or `–` instead of `-` or some other characters that are hard to catch.

I'd like to get a visual indicator (e.g. a red background) that these are special characters.

I found some plugins to have the same intent but they don't work for my example:

- https://github.com/Konfekt/vim-unicode-homoglyphs (catches one character)
- https://github.com/vim-utils/vim-troll-stopper (catches none)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help from Konfekt/vim-unicode-homoglyphs and [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16988346/52817) I found this solution that works quite well and has (almost?) no performance impact:

```
augroup Hiunicode
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter *
      \ syntax match nonascii "[^\x00-\x7F]" |
      \ highlight nonascii ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=red
augroup END
```

Comment: Yep, this is basically what I recommended in my answer.

Comment: FYI essentially a "synonym" for `[^\x00-\x7F]` you could use : `[^[:graph:][:cntrl:][:blank:]]`. That says anything that's not an ASCII printable character, ASCII control character or space/tab. Use  `[^[:graph:][:blank:]]` if you want to see control characters, too, which probabl shouldn't be in a file.

Comment: (The last one won't highlight control characters representing line endings and tabs, though. That would have rendered it useless.)

Answer (score 1):

I have a pretty general approach to this in `~/.vim/plugin/badwords.vim` which I'll put here (word list subject to opinion). You could easily modify the list to capture the characters you care about. The file highlights all the words automatically (as long as the buffer has some `syntax`) *and* provides a global `:Badsearch` command to put all occurences in the quickfix list. It also supports defining `g:badwords` to extend the list.

Another option is to loop through the range of unicode-codepoints (or build a representative character class) and handle them in a similar way.

---

```
" ~/.vim/plugin/badwords.vim
if exists('g:loaded_badwords')
  finish
endif
let g:loaded_badwords = 1

" obvious obviously
" basic basically
" simple simply
" of course
" clear clearly
" just
" everyone knows
" However,
" easy
" utilize utilized utilization utilizes
let s:badwords = [
      \ '\<obvious\(ly\)\?\>',
      \ '\<basic\(ally\)\?\>',
      \ '\<simpl\(e\|y\)\>',
      \ '\<of course\>',
      \ '\<clear\(ly\)\?\>',
      \ '\<just\>',
      \ '\<everyone knows\>',
      \ '\<However\>,',
      \ '\<easy\>',
      \ '\<utiliz\(e\w\?\|ation\)\>',
      \ ]

hi def link Badword ErrorMsg
function s:mark_bad(word) abort
  let l:pattern = printf('/\c%s/', a:word)
  exec 'syn match Badword' l:pattern 'containedin=ALL'
endfunction

augroup Badword
  autocmd!
  autocmd Syntax * for word in get(g:, 'badwords', []) + s:badwords | call s:mark_bad(word) | endfor
augroup END

command -bang -nargs=? -complete=file Badsearch
      \ execute 'vimgrep'
      \ '/'.join(get(g:, 'badwords', []) + s:badwords, '\|').'/'.(<bang>0 ? 'g' : '')
      \ (empty(<q-args>) ? expand('%') : <q-args>)
```

Comment: Thank you but I did not want to hunt for characters.